# Compare very large dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, data-comparison

I am trying to compare two very large dataframes, each with around 10 petabytes of data in Spark. The execution is throwing out of memory e this.issues even after increasing the memory configurations. Could anyone suggest a better alternative to solve this?

Approach I am using:

1. Generate row_hashes for each dataframe
2. diff = df.select('row_hash') - df1.select('row_hash')
3. diff.join(df, df.columns.toSeq, "inner")

Comment: It may be self-evident to you, but why are you comparing the data frames?  Do you need "strict" accuracy or "fuzzy" accuracy?  If the latter, what definition are you using?  The answer by @mamonu below seems good enough to me, but if "strict" accuracy is needed, it may not be good enough.  I could envision some sort of partitioning of the frame so you could compare subsets, but I am not really familiar with this technology, so I can only speak in generalities.

Comment: This is part of a migration project. So, we would like to identify even the smallest of differences in the data. So the comparison needs to be very accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spark's LSH implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/ml-features.html#locality-sensitive-hashing) to hash both dataframes into lower dimensions with a very strict similarity measure. After hashing, you can perform an [approxSimilarityJoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.MinHashLSHModel.html#pyspark.ml.feature.MinHashLSHModel.approxSimilarityJoin)

Some basic code on how to do this:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinHashLSH
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create feature vectors
df = df.withColumn("features", Vectors.dense(col("feature_col1"), col("feature_col2")))
df1 = df1.withColumn("features", Vectors.dense(col("feature_col1"), col("feature_col2")))

# Initialize LSH model
mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes", numHashTables=5)

# Fit the model and transform data
model = mh.fit(df)
df_hashed = model.transform(df)
df1_hashed = model.transform(df1)

# Approximate join to find potential matches
approx_joined_df = model.approxSimilarityJoin(df_hashed, df1_hashed, 0.1, distCol="JaccardDistance")

# Filter based on a distance threshold for very very similar items
filtered_df = approx_joined_df.filter("JaccardDistance < 0.05")
```

This method should be certainly better than a straight comparison. However you might find that for the kind of scale you are talking about you will certainly need to play with the config settings as well.